# Reporting Services transposing part of a table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a table that looks something like this

```
Product | Language | Cost
----------------------------
X       | En       | 5
X       | D        | 5
Y       | Jp       | 10
Y       | Sp        | 10
```

And I want it to look like this

```
Product | En | D | Jp | Sp
-------------------
X       | 5  | 5 | 0  | 0
Y       | 0  | 0 | 10 | 10
```

So what I want to do is to take all the values in the Language column and use them as column headers (done by printing the column as a row) and then match the Cost value to the new table where the the different languages are headers instead of values in a column.

How to do this in Reporting Services? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a matrix with columns grouped by Language and rows by Product, as follows[image]

Gives

[image]

**Edit**

Or with the new data set gives the following

[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you for you answer. I think I expressed myself poorly so I updated my question. I hope this doesn't cause any trouble for you. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: don't understand how this is different? The solution provided should still give the desired output of Languages as column headers in the report

Comment: Your original answer does indeed work. I underestimated Reporting Services and your answer. Thanks a bunch!